# Why does "Leap" sometimes not generate Fury?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

In the tooltip for the Barbarian skill "Leap" the info says "Generate 15 Fury".  Those who play with me know that I leap around like a fool constantly, but I've checked, and I often gain 0 Fury by doing this.  Bug, or am I missing something?

[image: Leap Tooltip]

Comment: I think that you have to leap on an enemy for the fury to generate.  I don't know for sure, so this isn't an actual answer.

Comment: Wild guess for you to do some testing: does it only generate fury when you actually hit something, whether it be a mob or a destructible object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of the Barbarian abilities which generate fury only generate fury when they hit something -  that means an enemy *or* a destructible item.

Don't **you** get angry when you leap into a pile of books? I know *my* barbarian does.

Comment: Algebra is for chumps.

Comment: Close to the exact same answer - checked this one because it was first.  I think this stinks about the Leap ability.  If I hit enemies or boxes, I get Fury anyway.  I guess I get more fury if I Leap, but it would be nice if I could at least give me a little when I don't hit anything, since I'm burning a cooldown.  Looks like my barbarian will be furiously leaping into a lot of rotten wood in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this one as well. If you use an offensive Fury Generating skill and do not hit anything (destructible items **do** count) You will generate 0 Fury. Also, Fury generated by hitting even an object like a jar holds the same decay rules as any other attack. It will take about 6 seconds to begin decaying.